# GXT how to display a tree-object in a XTemplate?

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have the following problem:
I am displaying Data of my GXT-project in a rever complex XTemplate.

```
@XTemplate(source = "DepictionDisplay.html")
    SafeHtml displayoben(String shortName, String inventoryNumber, String cave, String wall, String expedition, String vendor, String purchaseDate, String currentLocation, String stateOfPreservation, SafeUri imageUri, SafeUri fullImageUri,
            SafeUri realCaveSketchUri, double width, double height, String style, String modeOfRepresentation, String description, String generalRemarks, String otherSuggestedIdentifications);
```

The relevant part of DepictionDisplay.html is:

```
            <table class="data-view">
                <tpl if="inventoryNumber != &quot;&quot;">
                <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid black">
                        <td class="data-view-left"><i>Inventory No.</i></td>
                        <td class="data-view-right">{inventoryNumber}</td>
                </tr>
                </tpl>
                <tpl if="cave != &quot;&quot;">
                <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid black">
                        <td class="data-view-left"><i>Located in Cave</i></td>
                        <td class="data-view-right">{cave}</td>

                </tr>
                </tpl>
                <tpl if="wall != &quot;&quot;">
                <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid black">
                        <td class="data-view-left"><i>Position in cave</i></td>
                        <td class="data-view-right">{wall}</td>
                </tr>
                </tpl>
                <tpl if="expedition != &quot;&quot;">
                <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid black">
                        <td class="data-view-left"><i>Acquired by expedition</i></td>
                        <td class="data-view-right">{expedition}</td>
                </tr>
                </tpl>
                <tpl if="vendor != &quot;&quot;">
                <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid black">
                        <td class="data-view-left"><i>Vendor</i></td>
                        <td class="data-view-right">{vendor}</td>
                </tr>
                </tpl>
                <tpl if="purchaseDate != &quot;&quot;">
                <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid black">
                        <td class="data-view-left"><i>Purchase Date</i></td>
                        <td class="data-view-right">{purchaseDate}</td>
                </tr>
                </tpl>
                <tpl if="currentLocation != &quot;&quot;">
                <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid black">
                        <td class="data-view-left"><i>Current location</i></td>
                        <td class="data-view-right">{currentLocation}</td>
                </tr>
                </tpl>
                <tpl if="stateOfPreservation != &quot;&quot;">
                <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid black">
                        <td class="data-view-left"><i>State of preservation</i></td>
                        <td class="data-view-right">{stateOfPreservation}</td>
                </tr>
                </tpl>
                <tpl if="style != &quot;&quot;">
                <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid black">
                        <td class="data-view-left"><i>Style</i></td>
                        <td class="data-view-right">{style}</td>
                </tr>
                </tpl>
                <tpl if="modeOfRepresentation != &quot;&quot;">
                <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid black">
                        <td class="data-view-left"><i>Mode of representation</i></td>
                        <td class="data-view-right">{modeOfRepresentation}</td>
                </tr>
                </tpl>
        </table>
```

The Problem is, that lately, I had to change the former String Value of **wall** to a tree-object. 
The entries of the tree object have a getchildren() function to navigate down and a getText() function to access the String value, which is to be displayed.

My question is now: How can I display a Tree-Object inside this Table? So far, I did not find a suitable option as the tree can have a changing depth.

Any Ideas are more then appreciated.

Sincerely,

Erik

Answer (score 0):

XTemplates can take `SafeHtml` params, and insert that content, and have support for calling simple formatting functions, but cannot call themselves or other functions recursively.

Consider iterating through that `getChildren()` and appending each of their rendered template to a `SafeHtmlBuilder`, then pass the resulting SafeHtml string to the parent. Your own code then does the recursion, inserting smaller bits of content into bigger ones.